# Trasfer music while playing on the android phone to a bluetooth module

Tags: android

I want to transfer music ( not with speaker ) through bluetooth while playing it on the phone. At this time the bluetooth module will catch the information sent and will make LED animations, please help me with the code in java at application.

```
public void switchOn() {
    try {

        connectedThread.write("0".getBytes());

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LED: On.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

This is a simple code I made to transfer data to a bluetooth module, but "connectedThread.write();" function can only send string data.

Comment: You have to show us some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: We will surely help you but before that you need to show some attempt, on which you are stuck.